# Pressure in a container with constant outflow

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Given is a container with a volume of 100 cubic meters. The content (CO2) is under a relative pressure of 100 mbar and has a constant temperature of 35 °C.

A constant flow of 60 cubic meters per hour (relative to 50 mbar) is exiting the container.

**When will a pressure of 30 mbar be reached in the container?**

I would use the ideal gas law:

PV=nRT

T=35+273.15=308.15 K

R=8.314 J/(molK)

Amount of substance: Container volume at 100 mbar:

V1=100 m3

P1=100 mbar+1 bar=1.1 bar=110,000 Pa

n1=P1⋅V/R⋅T

n1=1.1 bar⋅100 m3/0.08206 L⋅bar/(mol⋅K)⋅308.15 K

n1=4,293.6 mol

Amount of substance: Withdrawal flow Q (per hour) relative to 50 mbar:

V2=60 m3

P2=50 mbar+1 bar=105,000 Pa

n2=P2⋅V2/R⋅T

n2=105,000 Pa⋅60 m3/8.314 J/(molK)⋅308.15 K

n2=2,459.1 mol

Amount of substance: Container volume at 30 mbar:

V3=V1

P3=30 mbar+1 bar=1.03 bar=103,000 Pa

n3=P3⋅V3/R⋅T

n3=103,000 Pa⋅100 m/38.314 J/(molK)⋅308.15 K

n3=4,020.4 mol

The sought time is then

1 h⋅(n1−n2)/n3 = 1 h⋅(4,293.6−4,020.4) mol / 2,459.1 mol=0.11 h=6.7 min

Is this correct?